# How does Disqus know that I am the website I am pretending to be?

Tags: javascript, disqus

I am adding Disqus to my website  and using the Universal Code.

See [here](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717112-universal-embed-code)

I am getting their javascript at mywebsite.disqus.com/embed.js.

How does Disqus know that I am mywebsite.com and not another one ?
What prevents someone else to use this javascript embed ?

I guess they check the origin URL to verify the request comes from mywebsite.com.

What other checks do they use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation on the page you linked, you have to provide a `PAGE_IDENTIFIER`.

```
// Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER;
```

It goes on to explain

> **this.page.identifier** tells Disqus a unique value, used to identify the page and discussion thread

Yes, someone else could theoretically copy your identifier and embed it into their site. However, Discus probably prevents this using a cross origin header to ensure only you can load the following URL.

```
// IMPORTANT: Replace EXAMPLE with your forum shortname!
s.src = 'https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';
```

Your shortcode is probably associated with a domain in the Discus backend, so when you call that unique URL with your shortcode in it, that request will contain a cross origin header that is specific to your domain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! How safe are cross origin headers ? Is it possible to forge them ?

Comment: @jreid this is a totally different question that you should either research or ask separately on SO. Don't forget to mark this answer correct.